# Returning pretty JSON error codes from Django REST framework

Tags: python, json, django, error-handling, django-rest-framework

I need my API to serve explicit error codes for UI applications, that will look similar to i.e. GitHub API:

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Content-Length: 149

{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "resource": "Issue",
      "field": "title",
      "code": "missing_field"
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the best way to implement it in DRF? Is there any package to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how i do it, if it suits your needs:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

if serializer.is_valid():
            ..... # Do my logic here
            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
return Response({
    'status' : 'Bad request',
    'message': 'Account could not be created with received data.',
    'errors' : serializer.errors # for example
}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```